# How do I format JavaScript program in TextMate?

Tags: textmate

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("body").hide().fadeIn(250);
})
```

If I place the cursor at the end of the above code (the only lines of code in the file and the file is saved as sample.js) and press ^Q, a *carriage return* is added at the end.

If I select all the three lines and press ^Q, The code gets formatted as below.

```
$(document).ready(function() { $("body").hide().fadeIn(250); })
```

If I select the code snippet at the top and press ^J, I again get

```
$(document).ready(function() { $("body").hide().fadeIn(250); })
```

What should I do to get the code formatted as below?

```
document).ready(function() {
    $("body").hide().fadeIn(250);
})
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the Javascript tmbundle, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>